# Most efficient data structure for inserts and then sort with a different condition

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, insert

I was wondering what would be the best data structure for reading from a text the differents word and doing the frequency table, sorted by decreasing number of appearances.

My idea was using a struct:

```
struct info {
    string word;
    int num;
};
```

Having this in mind I was wondering what I should use: vector, set, list...?
I've two implementations with vector:

1) Having the vector unsorted and have a linear search of the word, if the word is not at the vector I add the element at the end. Wheb i finished reading the words I sorted the vector by decreasing frequency.

2) Having the vector sorted and use a dicotomic search, adding the element to its corresponding position or adding 1 to the num if it was. Then i sorted the vector by decreasing frequency.

What do you think, what is it the best way of doing this kind of exercise?

Comment: You could use a `std::map<std::string,int>` to count particular words.

Comment: The think is that i have to use 2 types of sort: First using the alphabetical order and then sort by the frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> dictionary;

//where words is a list, vector of your words, replace this with reading from your text file word by word
for(const auto& word : words)
{
  dictionary[word]++;
}

//now the dictionary has your words in alphabetical order and the frequency (number of occurrences)
std::multimap<int, std::string> histogram;
for(const auto& elem : dictionary )
{
   histogram.insert(std::make_pair(elem.second(), elem.first()));
}

//print the histogram
for(const auto& elem : histogram)
{
  cout << elem.first() << " : " << elem.second() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment (sorry, too difficult to type to give credits) you could use a `std::map`. A maps elements are sorted and you save the extra effort of doing that "by hand". If you need two different ways of sorting you could use two maps or some other container and sort that twice. E.g. with a vector:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct info {
    std::string word;
    int num;
};

bool sortViaNum(const info& a,const info& b)  { return a.num > b.num; }
bool sortViaWord(const info& a,const info& b) { return a.word > b.word; }

int main() {

    std::vector<info> vect;
    // fill the vector
    std::sort(vect.begin(),vect.end(),sortViaNum);
    std::sort(vect.begin(),vect.end(),sortViaWord);
    return 0;
}
```